# Inno Setup: Associating a range of file extensions

Tags: inno-setup

Is there a way in Inno setup to register a range of file extensions with a program?

What I want to do is set up a file associations page and ask the user if he wants to associate files with the extension n1..n99 with my program.

I can see how the tasks page works with individual file types, but I want to register 100 file extensions in one go. As it stands this would put 100 check boxes on the Associate files page.

Can this be done with pascal script, anybody got any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: The simplest way is to iterate in a For I:= 1 to 99 loop.